# Sharepoint 2010 Apply a master page without designer?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, master-pages

I have been tasked with updating a master page on a sharepoint 2010 site. I'm a bit new to sharepoint, and everything I have found gives directions using sharepoint designer. Problem is the site I am changing has disabled designer.

SO I have made changes on a sandbox site and have uploaded the new master page to the target site, but now I can't find out to apply the master page to the site, or how to create a page based on my master page. In site settings, look and feel, I do not have a master page option.. is there just a permission issue, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your site does not have publishing enabled then you will need sharepoint designer to set the Master Page.

To set the Master page without designer you will need to activate publishing feature. TO do that you will need to:

- Activate the publishing feature at site collection level (**SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure**),
- Activate the publishing feature at site level (**SharePoint Server Publishing**)

After you activate these two features, You can then see the Masterpage option on the site settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the change master page - page directly. Its a layouts page.

So the steps are -

1.make sure your master page is uploaded, checked in and published.

2.Then access the page http:///_layouts/changesitemasterpage.aspx.

3.Change the masterpage.